# Usage of @RequestParam throws error in Spring 3

Tags: spring, annotations

I am using the @RequestParam annotation to get the request parameters , and using the same to insert the values into the DB.
I have setup the controller to re-direct to the same page which contains the text fields for the user to enter the values, which are being read using the @RequestParam annotation.

But after I enter the values into the text fields , and click submit , it throws this error

> Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Name for argument type [java.lang.String] not available, and parameter name information not found in class file either.

I am a newbie to Spring 3 , and unable to understand the error. Can anybody please shed light on the same.

Thanks in advance,
Vivek

Comment: Which version of Spring MVC? Can you show method's signature with annotations?

Comment: I am using Spring MVC version 3 , and the method signature is 

`public void insertRecords(@RequestParam String id , @RequestParam String name , @RequestParam String addr)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to inject the value of request parameter into your handler method parameter, either one of the following should be satisfied

1. The name of the request parameter must match the name of the method parameter.
   e.g.
   Following will inject the request parameter named "studentName" into the method parameter studentName

   `public String goToStep(@RequestParam String studentName)`
2. The request parameter name must be explicitly specified if it does not match the method parameter. The following will inject "nameOfStudent" request parameter into studentName:

   `public String goToStep(@RequestParam("nameOfStudent") String studentName)`

Please post your handler method code if your issue continues to persist.

Comment: I followed the guideline outlined , and accordingly all the param names are correct. Please find mentioned below the handler method code.

`public void insertRecords(@RequestParam String id , @RequestParam String name , @RequestParam String addr)`

and the corresponding jsp has the id attributes for each of the text fields as per the naming convention of the method parameter.

Comment: Check if the request parameter can be accessed from the servlet layer. Like this:

`code`
public void insertRecords(@RequestParam String id , @RequestParam String name , @RequestParam String addr, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println( request.getParameter( "name" ) ); // Do not use in production
}
`code`

If this prints "null" then the JSP is not sending the parameter and posting your relevant JSP code will be useful. If it prints the value you are expecting, then we know the issue is with the controller.

Answer (score 5):

I asked for the version you are using because I ran with a similar problem a few days ago. I was using Spring 3.1.0.M2 and the same exception appeared when I was using @PathVariable in proxied @Controller.

It was caused by a [resolved known bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8464). You just have to switch to 3.0.6 or try the nightly build 3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Of course, the latter option is not recommended for production environment.

Comment: I am new to Spring and do not know how to include 3.0.6 or 3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. I am using spring mvc. What is the exact dependency/process for switching to this? Thanks @sinuhepop